# Perron solution and weak solution for a Dirichlet problem in a convex domain

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Consider $\Omega  \subset R^n$ an open, bounded and convex set. Then your boundary is Lipschtz.

Then we can define the trace operator T. Consider $K \subset \partial \Omega$ a compact set with non empty interior and $g : \partial \Omega \rightarrow R$ defined by $g(x) = 1 $ for $x \in K$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x \in \partial \Omega \setminus K .$

Consider the following problem:

Find $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$  a weak solution for the problem (lets call problem 1)

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\Delta u = 0,  \ in \  \Omega  \\
u = g \ in \  \partial \Omega \ (\ in \ trace  \ sense\ ) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

This problem has a unique solution in the Sobolev space $H^{1}(\Omega)$.

Now if we use the classic Perron method (the method works by the convexity of $\Omega$) we can construct a function $u: \Omega \rightarrow R$ satisfying:

i) $\Delta u = 0 \ on \ \Omega$ and $u \in C^{2}(\Omega)$

ii)$\displaystyle\lim_{y \rightarrow x} u(y) = g(x)$ if $g$ is continuous in $x \in \partial \Omega$

My question is : the function given by the Perron method and  the unique solution for the problem  (1) are the same ?

I am studying an article an appears the author use this. I searched a lot in the literature but I did not find anything... Please, someone can answer the question or say to me a reference?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $\Omega$ is a bounded domain, $C^2(\Omega)\subset H^1(\Omega)$. It remains simply to check that the limit condition (ii) is at least as strong as the condition $u = g$ on $\partial\Omega$ in the trace sense. This however is not immediately obvious to me. Do you have anything more about $K$ besides what you stated? I am worried a bit about the case where $K$ contains something like a fat Cantor set.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have more conditions on $K$ =(

Comment: Can you include a reference to the article? Maybe there's something else that he is using.

Comment: @WillieWong of course =) . My question is about the function $u_{\Omega}$ mencioned in the beginnning of the page 2 of this article :http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/12/87/60/PDF/fbpLaplacian.pdf

Comment: "unfortunately I don't have more conditions on $K$" That is wrong. Look at the first page of your document. $K$ is a subset of $\{x_1 = 0\}$ (I think there is a small typo, but that's what they meant), and is smooth, convex, and bounded. In particular, the boundary set of $K$ has codimension 1. So you can apply Perron method's convergence result almost everywhere on $\partial\Omega$ (in fact, on $\partial\Omega \setminus \partial K$).

Comment: I did a great mistake. i believed the conditions that you sayed are not important. this is a great mistake from my part. Sorry Willie Wong

Comment: thanks for your attention =)

Comment: @WillieWong, please can you indicate to me a standard reference that studies this type of arguments (in the case of the laplacean)?

Comment: Um... what do you mean by "this type of arguments"? If you mean the type of statement "classical solutions are weak solutions, therefore uniqueness of weak solutions implies uniqueness of classical solutions" then usually this just follows from the definition, and doesn't require much argument. The cases where some argument needs to be given to say that a classical solution is a weak solution often involve a very technical setting and usually are dealt with on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: when i said  "this type of arguments" i was talking about the part when you say that "K has codimension one".  i read your last comment, and i understand the comment, i was not seeing the facts that you wrote in your last comment, i dont know why, maybe i was sleppy. thanks for your attention and help !! =D

Comment: Ah. Note first what I wrote is that the boundary set of $K$, namely $\partial K$ (where boundary is taken relative to $\partial\Omega$ or equivalently $\{x_1 = 0\}$), is codimension 1. There are many way to see this. One way is to note that if you fix a point $p$ in the interior of $K$, by convexity you can write $\partial K$ as a graph in polar/spherical coordinates centered at $p$ of some function $r = r(\omega)$. Furthermore this function is smooth by assumption. Hence the conclusion.

Comment: you're right. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the statement that u is in H^1 is not correct. The boundary data here is not in H^(1/2)(bdy) as it is a discontinuous step function. Similarly the
Perron construction doesn't work as the boundary data is not continuous. 
Nevertheless there is a unique solution of this problem in certain H^s spaces with s < 1. See the paper by Auchmuty on Reproducing Kernels for spaces of Real Harmonic functions in SIAM J Math Anal, 41, 1994-2001.